# Is it possible to style the ion-img class?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I tried to include a height and width in the image using the  class in Scss, and saw that nothing happens. Is it only possible to change the height or width inline?

**HTML**

```
  <div class="footer">
    <ion-img src="../../../assets/imgs/logo.png" 
    alt="Logo"></ion-img>
  </div>
</ion-footer>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer {
  ion-img {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Its should be work. Try add this; overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pierce the shadow Dom.

```
.footer {
  ::ng-deep ion-img {
    width:40px!important;
    height:40px!important;
  }
}
```